# keras nan loss when using custom mape loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I built a simple lstm network and used a costom mape loss as follows:

```
def custom_mape(y_true, y_pred):
    mapes = K.switch(K.equal(y_true, 0), y_true, 100*K.abs(y_true - y_pred)/y_true)
    return K.mean(mapes, axis=-1)
```

And the loss turned to be nan at the very beginning:

```
Model: "sequential_93"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_163 (LSTM)              (None, 14, 1)             296       
=================================================================
Total params: 296
Trainable params: 296
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/50
410/410 [==============================] - 3s 7ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 2/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 3/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 4/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 5/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 6ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 6/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/50
410/410 [==============================] - 3s 6ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 8/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 9/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 10/50
410/410 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
```

Here are some ways I tried:

1. When I change K.abs(y_true - y_pred)/y_true to K.abs(y_true - y_pred), the network works.
2. To figure out if it is gradient explosion, I tried clipvalue=1, lr=0 and batchsize =1 separately. The loss remains nan.

Besides, I used min-max normalization for y and a sample of y is as follows:

```
[[1.84368752e-05],
[9.86574098e-04],
[8.09853832e-04]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
K.abs(y_true - y_pred)/y_true
```

Here, if `y_true` is `0`, you would get nan because you're trying to divide by `0`.

Comment: But there is K.switch(K.equal(y_true, 0), y_true, 100*K.abs....) which means if y_true is 0 it returns y_true(zero). Thus, zero won't be as denominator.

Comment: Did you try logging your `mapes` values?

Comment: Another thing is to check types of `y_pred` and `y_true` @Ricardo

Comment: Actually the difference between mapes and K.mean(mapes, axis=-1) is shape. For example, if mapes is [[50],[100],[20]], K.mean(mapes, axis=-1)  returns [50, 100, 20]

Comment: Thanks for your response. May i ask in which step I need to check the types?

Comment: I see, if you want to return a single value from K.mean() discard axis argument, so `K.mean([[50],[100],[20]])` would return 56 (Because your values are integers).

For checking types, do it as the first thing in your `custom_mape` function. If one type is `float32` and the other one is `integer`, might yield to errors.